# Existence of periodic solution in an ODE system

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let the ODE system,

\begin{cases}x'(t)=x^3+x^5 \\ y'(t)=y+y^7 \end{cases}

defined in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I need to say if this system supports periodic solution with period $T>0$.

This is a question of Analysis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ not ODE, that is, I need to demonstrate this using concepts presented in Analysis in $\mathbb{R}^n$, my textbook is *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres. The hint is,

> A periodic solution of the system above is a closed curve $\gamma(t) = (x(t), y (t))$ that satisfies the system.

I believe I have to use Stokes, but I am not able to proceed with the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider the curve $\phi = (x, y)$ and take the squared distance to the origin $x^2 + y^2$. The derivative of this is
$$2(x\dot{x} + y\dot{y}) = 2(x^4 + x^6 + y^2 + y^8)\ge 0.$$
If this curve is periodic, then it is actually a closed curve and so a compact subset of the plane so there must be a minimum of this distance, corresponding to a point closest to the origin.
Since it is a sum of squares this means $x = y = 0$ at that point, so your curve goes through the origin, but clearly the constant curve $\phi\equiv 0$ satisfies the equation and it can be the only one doing that.

If you wanted to conclude this from Stokes Theorem you need to integrate the 1-form
$$(x^3 + x^5)dx + (y + y^7)dy$$ along the line given by a potential closed curve, i.e. around $\phi$ and if $D$ is the interior, assuming $T$ is the minimum period so that you avoid self intersections, you conclude
$$\int_C (x^3 + x^5)dx + (y + y^7)dy = \int\int_D \dfrac{d(y + y^7)}{dx} - \dfrac{d(x^3 + x^5)}{dy} dxdy = 0.$$
But, by definition of evaluating a line integral, this is the same as
$$\int_C (x^3 + x^5)dx + (y + y^7)dy = \int \phi'(t)\cdot\phi'(t) dt,$$
where we have used that $\phi$ satisfies the differential equation to get the first $\phi'$. The integrand is nonnegative and since it integrates to $0$, it is equal to $0$ everywhere in the interval it is defined. That is, $\phi \equiv 0$.

Comment: Is it really so obvious that $\phi \equiv \vec{0}$ is the only solution passing through the origin? As I mentioned in the other comment you can think of $y'=|y|^{1/2},y(0)=0$. Somehow you need uniqueness to make this line of reasoning work as written, and that uniqueness is arguably excluded by not using ODE methods. (Of course, even if you didn't have uniqueness, as soon as it leaves the origin it would begin to shoot away from the origin, which was the main point of the argument.)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's obvious. It is using the fact that ODE's with enough regularity conditions have unique solutions that have the same regularity. In this case the system is smooth, so solutions to it are unique and adquire the same smoothness. Since constant to $0$ satisfies it has to be the one.

This enough "regularity" I mentions is what is needed on the proof of existence and uniqueness, which is the required analytic condition for Banach fixed point theorem works in the proof.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $x^3 + x^5 > 0$ when $x > 0$, $< 0$ when $x < 0$.  Similarly for $y + y^7$.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a solution that is periodic in $(x(t),y(t))$, then also functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ have to be periodic separately, as real functions.

Further, the system is decoupled, you have two scalar, non-coupled autonomous ODE of first order. Scalar autonomous first-order ODE do not have periodic solutions, their solutions are constant or (strictly) monotonous (assuming the right side function is locally Lipschitz or differentiable).

Comment: That last clarification isn't totally true, consider $y'=|y|^{1/2}$. The point in this example is that *non-uniqueness* can create a bridge between a constant solution and a monotone solution. So in this problem it suffices to show that the IVPs have unique solutions.

Comment: I guess that the op wants a solution using only results and techniques of analysis in R^n

Comment: @user2345678 : What is wrong with using the special results for $n=1$? Anything that is periodic in $(x,y)$ has also to be periodic in $x$ and $y$ separately, which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The decoupled dynamic system can be integrated as follows

$$
\cases{
\frac{dx}{x^3+x^5}= dt\\
\frac{dy}{y+y^7}= dt
}\ \ \Rightarrow \cases{\ln \left(x^2+1\right)-2 \ln (x)-\frac{1}{x^2}=2t\\ \ln (y)-\frac{1}{6} \ln \left(y^6+1\right)=t}\ \ \Rightarrow \cases{\psi(x) = 2t\\ \phi(y) = t}
$$

As can be verified $\psi, \phi$ are analytic strict increasing functions in $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ so their inverses $x=\psi^{-1}(t), y=\phi^{-1}(t)$ are also strict increasing functions. The conclusion is that under such circumstances no periodic orbit is possible.